# How to set a service account for using the JIRA API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, service-accounts

I am working on a service that logs into JIRA and performs few operations that are not associated with a particular user. Right now, I'm using a virtual account and authenticating the JIRA by the accounts username and password. The use case requires a significant number of such services to be created. The current solution will be messy to maintain, because I need to keep a track of service level logs, which will require creation of a large number of virtual accounts, whose management is difficult. Is there a service account like concept in JIRA that allows a service to perform authentication as an application like on Google cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their [reference](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/?utm_source=%2Fcloud%2Fjira%2Fplatform%2Frest%2F&utm_medium=302#version) about the REST API.

I played with it once, remember it requires API key or token maybe.